# Can't show image depending on item selected from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

Trying to display an image depending on what user selects from dropdown list. Right now, it only displays image 2 when I select image 1 and I can not figure out what the problem is.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

Chose an image:
<select id = "choice">
    <option>Image 1</option>
    <option>Image 2</option>
</select>

<button onclick = "showImage()">Show image</button>
<img src = " " id = "chosenImage" width = 250 height = 250>
    <script>
    function showImage(){
        var dropDownName = document.getElementById("choice");
        var imageChosen = dropDownName.options[dropDownName.selectedIndex].text;
        if (imageChosen == "image 1"){
            document.getElementById("chosenImage").src = "land.jpg";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("chosenImage").src = "code.png";
        }
    }
    </script>

</BODY>


</HTML>
```

Comment: `'Image 1' != 'image 1'`

Comment: Here is a cleaner version https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v0bfg91c/ I recommend to not have spaces in the attribute assignments and use all lowercase tags in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `value` attribute to the `option` elements then use that as your basis for identifying what to show.

**1st Example:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Chose an image:
    <select id = "choice">
      <option value="default">Default</option>
      <option value="image_1">Image 1</option>
      <option value="image_2">Image 2</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick = "showImage()">Show image</button>
    <img src="https://4197r62cmrjs32n9dndpi2o1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/square-placeholder.jpg" id="chosenImage" width='250' height ='250'>
    
    <script>
      function showImage() {
        var dropDownName = document.getElementById("choice");
        var imageChosen = dropDownName.options[dropDownName.selectedIndex].value;

        if (imageChosen == "image_1"){
          imageChosen = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png";
        } else if (imageChosen == 'image_2') {
          imageChosen = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg/2048px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png';
        } else {
           imageChosen = "https://4197r62cmrjs32n9dndpi2o1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/square-placeholder.jpg";
        }
        document.getElementById("chosenImage").src = imageChosen;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can just shorten it by placing the path to your image in the `value` attribute as shown below.

**2nd Example:**

```html
<html>

<body>
  Chose an image:
  <select id="choice">
    <option value="https://4197r62cmrjs32n9dndpi2o1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/square-placeholder.jpg">Default</option>
    <option value="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png">Image 1</option>
    <option value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg/2048px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png">Image 2</option>
  </select>

  <button onclick="showImage()">Show image</button>
  <img src="https://4197r62cmrjs32n9dndpi2o1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/square-placeholder.jpg" id="chosenImage" width='250' height='250'>

  <script>
    function showImage() {
      var dropDownName = document.getElementById("choice");
      var imageChosen = dropDownName.options[dropDownName.selectedIndex].value;

      document.getElementById("chosenImage").src = imageChosen;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

`if (imageChosen == "image 1"){`

it should be
`if (imageChosen == "Image 1"){`
with I capitalize

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Did you read the other answers and the comments before answering? Please do not answer typo type questions t- especially not if they already have comments and answers

Comment: OK, thank you @mplungjan for the guidance.